# Why an RPC call would return access denied when running as a local admin?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, rpc

I am just getting started with Windows RPC programming.  I am trying to interact with the Windows Event log system through [ms-even6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-even6/18000371-ae6d-45f7-95f3-249cbe2be39b).  Microsoft does not cover secure RPC calls in its tutorials, and I couldn't find much about it anywhere. So far, I have the following code ...

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "ms-even6_h.h"
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "rpcrt4.lib")

int main()
{
    RPC_STATUS status;
    RPC_WSTR pszUuid = NULL;
    RPC_WSTR pszProtocolSequence = reinterpret_cast<RPC_WSTR>(const_cast<PWSTR>(L"ncacn_np"));
    RPC_WSTR pszNetworkAddress = NULL;
    RPC_WSTR pszEndpoint = reinterpret_cast<RPC_WSTR>(const_cast<PWSTR>(L"\\pipe\\eventlog"));
    RPC_WSTR pszOptions = NULL;
    RPC_WSTR pszStringBinding = NULL;
    unsigned long ulCode;

    status = RpcStringBindingCompose(pszUuid,
        pszProtocolSequence,
        pszNetworkAddress,
        pszEndpoint,
        pszOptions,
        &pszStringBinding);
    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcStringBindingCompose failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    status = RpcBindingFromStringBinding(pszStringBinding, &client_IfHandle);

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcBindingFromStringBinding failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    status = RpcBindingSetAuthInfo(client_IfHandle,
        0,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,
        0,
        0
    );

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcBindingSetAuthInfo failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    RpcTryExcept // This block always throw an Access Denied runtime exception
    {
        EvtRpcVariantList props;
        status = EvtRpcGetChannelConfig(L"Application", 0, &props);
        if (status)
        {
            std::cerr << "[-] EvtRpcGetChannelConfig failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
            exit(status);
        }
        std::cout << "[+] EvtRpcGetChannelConfig worked!" << std::endl;

    }
        RpcExcept(1)
    {
        ulCode = RpcExceptionCode();
        printf("Runtime reported exception 0x%lx = %ld\n", ulCode, ulCode);
    }
    RpcEndExcept

        status = RpcStringFree(&pszStringBinding);

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcStringFree failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    status = RpcBindingFree(&client_IfHandle);

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcBindingFree failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }
    std::cout << "[+] Done." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

/******************************************************/
/*         MIDL allocate and free                     */
/******************************************************/

void __RPC_FAR* __RPC_USER midl_user_allocate(size_t len)
{
    return (malloc(len));
}

void __RPC_USER midl_user_free(void __RPC_FAR* ptr)
{
    free(ptr);
}
```

I tried calling different RPC functions, and they all throw an access denied exception.  My client process is running as a local admin, and I am targeting my local machine.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

All help is appreciated!

#UPDATE

After reviewing [windows_protocols ms-even6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-even6/31f0897c-034e-490f-b5cc-f2dd824d7378), I changed the protocol sequence to *ncacn_ip_tcp*.  Now the **ACCESS DENIED** error seem to be gone but now I get a *Runtime reported exception 0x6f7 = 1783 (The stub received bad data.) error*.

```cpp
/* file: helloc.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "ms-even6_h.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>

#pragma comment(lib, "rpcrt4.lib")

int main()
{
    RPC_STATUS status;
    RPC_WSTR pszUuid = NULL;
    RPC_WSTR pszProtocolSequence = reinterpret_cast<RPC_WSTR>(const_cast<PWSTR>(L"ncacn_ip_tcp"));
    RPC_WSTR pszNetworkAddress = reinterpret_cast<RPC_WSTR>(const_cast<PWSTR>(L"localhost"));
    RPC_WSTR pszEndpoint = NULL;
    RPC_WSTR pszOptions = NULL;
    RPC_WSTR pszStringBinding = NULL;
    unsigned long ulCode;

    status = RpcStringBindingCompose(pszUuid,
        pszProtocolSequence,
        pszNetworkAddress,
        pszEndpoint,
        pszOptions,
        &pszStringBinding);
    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcStringBindingCompose failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    status = RpcBindingFromStringBinding(pszStringBinding, &client_IfHandle);

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcBindingFromStringBinding failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    status = RpcEpResolveBinding(
        client_IfHandle,
        IEventService_v1_0_c_ifspec
    );

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcEpResolveBinding failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    status = RpcBindingSetAuthInfo(client_IfHandle,
        0,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,
        0,
        0
    );

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcBindingSetAuthInfo failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    RpcTryExcept
    {
        EvtRpcVariantList props;
        status = EvtRpcGetChannelConfig(L"Application", (INT32)0, &props);
        if (status)
        {
            std::cerr << "[-] EvtRpcGetChannelConfig failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
            exit(status);
        }
        std::cout << "[+] EvtRpcGetChannelConfig worked!" << std::endl;

    }
        RpcExcept(1)
    {
        ulCode = RpcExceptionCode();
        std::cerr << "[-] Runtime reported exception 0x"
            << std::hex << ulCode
            << " = "
            << std::dec << ulCode
            << std::endl;
    }
    RpcEndExcept

        status = RpcStringFree(&pszStringBinding);

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcStringFree failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    status = RpcBindingFree(&client_IfHandle);

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcBindingFree failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }
    std::cout << "[+] Done." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

/******************************************************/
/*         MIDL allocate and free                     */
/******************************************************/

void __RPC_FAR* __RPC_USER midl_user_allocate(size_t len)
{
    return (malloc(len));
}

void __RPC_USER midl_user_free(void __RPC_FAR* ptr)
{
    free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Just to check, is the process running as admin?  Using an admin login by itself does not make an application run as admin.  You need to request admi rights in the manifest or to "run as administrator"

Comment: That is the case Dave, I am running the process from the process as High integrity.

Comment: Have you tried [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/bf44232a-ca5b-4ed6-8cca-8eee3f257ed1/rpc-call-to-remote-pc-gets-access-denied?forum=winserver2008appcompatabilityandcertification) ?

Comment: I solved the problem!
As I mentioned in my update, after reviewing the ms-even6 documentation, I changed the protocol sequence to ncacn_ip_tcp and adapted the code to it.
After that, I was still having issues with the calls.
What was the problem? I was using uninitialized pointers for the procedure arguments!
I will update the question with the working code in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing windows_protocols ms-even6, I changed the protocol sequence to ncacn_ip_tcp. Once that was done, the ACCESS DENIED error was gone, but I was still unable to call the remote procedures. The app would always fail either with *Runtime reported exception 0x6f7 = 1783 (The stub received bad data.)* or *Runtime reported exception 0x6c6 = 1734 (The array bounds are invalid.)*.

The reason? Uninitialized pointers!
Once I properly initialized my pointers and DWORDs, everything worked!

Here is a working example.

```cs
/* file: helloc.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "ms-even6_h.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "rpcrt4.lib")

int main()
{
    RPC_STATUS status;
    RPC_WSTR pszUuid = NULL;
    RPC_WSTR pszProtocolSequence = reinterpret_cast<RPC_WSTR>(const_cast<PWSTR>(L"ncacn_ip_tcp"));
    RPC_WSTR pszNetworkAddress = reinterpret_cast<RPC_WSTR>(const_cast<PWSTR>(L"localhost"));
    RPC_WSTR pszEndpoint = NULL;
    RPC_WSTR pszOptions = NULL;
    RPC_WSTR pszStringBinding = NULL;
    unsigned long ulCode;

    status = RpcStringBindingCompose(pszUuid,
        pszProtocolSequence,
        pszNetworkAddress,
        pszEndpoint,
        pszOptions,
        &pszStringBinding);
    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcStringBindingCompose failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    status = RpcBindingFromStringBinding(pszStringBinding, &client_IfHandle);

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcBindingFromStringBinding failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    status = RpcEpResolveBinding(
        client_IfHandle,
        IEventService_v1_0_c_ifspec
    );

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcEpResolveBinding failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    status = RpcBindingSetAuthInfo(client_IfHandle,
        0,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,
        0,
        0
    );

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcBindingSetAuthInfo failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    RpcTryExcept
    {
        PCONTEXT_HANDLE_LOG_HANDLE hLog;
        RpcInfo error;
        status = EvtRpcOpenLogHandle(L"Application", 1, &hLog, &error);
        if (status)
        {
            std::cerr << "[-] EvtRpcOpenLogHandle failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
            exit(status);
        }
        std::cout << "[+] EvtRpcOpenLogHandle worked!" << std::endl;


        status = EvtRpcClose(&hLog);
        if (status)
        {
            std::cerr << "[-] EvtRpcClose failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
            exit(status);
        }
        std::cout << "[+] EvtRpcClose worked!" << std::endl;

        EvtRpcVariantList props;
        props.count = 0;
        props.props = NULL;
        status = EvtRpcGetChannelConfig(L"Application", 0, &props);
        if (status)
        {
            std::cerr << "[-] EvtRpcGetChannelConfig failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
            exit(status);
        }
        std::cout << "[+] EvtRpcGetChannelConfig worked!" << std::endl;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < props.count; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "\tChannelConfig[" << i << "]:"
                << "\n\t\ttype: " << props.props[i].type
                << std::endl;
        }
        PCONTEXT_HANDLE_REMOTE_SUBSCRIPTION hSub;
        PCONTEXT_HANDLE_OPERATION_CONTROL hOpCtrl;
        DWORD dwQueryChannelInfoSize = 0;
        EvtRpcQueryChannelInfo* queryChannelInfo = NULL;
        status = EvtRpcRegisterRemoteSubscription(
            L"Application",
            L"*",
            NULL,
            0x00000002 | 0x00001000,
            &hSub,
            &hOpCtrl,
            &dwQueryChannelInfoSize,
            &queryChannelInfo,
            &error);
        if (status)
        {
            std::cerr << "[-] EvtRpcRegisterRemoteSubscription failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
            exit(status);
        }
        std::cout << "[+] EvtRpcRegisterRemoteSubscription worked!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\tdwQueryChannelInfoSize: " << dwQueryChannelInfoSize << std::endl;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < dwQueryChannelInfoSize; i++)
        {
            std::wcout << L"\tqueryChannelInfo[" << i << "]: "
                << queryChannelInfo[i].name
                << L" ("
                << queryChannelInfo[i].status
                << L")"
                << std::endl;

        }

        DWORD numRequestedRecords = 1;
        DWORD flags = 0;
        DWORD numActualRecords = 0;
        DWORD* eventDataIndices = NULL;
        DWORD* eventDataSizes = NULL;
        DWORD resultBufferSize = 0;
        BYTE* resultBuffer = NULL;
        status = EvtRpcRemoteSubscriptionNextAsync(
            hSub,
            numRequestedRecords,
            flags,
            &numActualRecords,
            &eventDataIndices,
            &eventDataSizes,
            &resultBufferSize,
            &resultBuffer
        );
        if (status)
        {
            std::cerr << "[-] EvtRpcRemoteSubscriptionNextAsync failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
            exit(status);
        }
        std::cout << "[+] EvtRpcRemoteSubscriptionNextAsync worked!" << std::endl;
    }
        RpcExcept(1)
    {
        ulCode = RpcExceptionCode();
        std::cerr << "[-] Runtime reported exception 0x"
            << std::hex << ulCode
            << " = "
            << std::dec << ulCode
            << std::endl;
    }
    RpcEndExcept

        status = RpcStringFree(&pszStringBinding);

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcStringFree failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }

    status = RpcBindingFree(&client_IfHandle);

    if (status) {
        std::cerr << "[-] RpcBindingFree failed [" << status << "]" << std::endl;
        exit(status);
    }
    std::cout << "[+] Done." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

/******************************************************/
/*         MIDL allocate and free                     */
/******************************************************/

void __RPC_FAR* __RPC_USER midl_user_allocate(size_t len)
{
    return (malloc(len));
}

void __RPC_USER midl_user_free(void __RPC_FAR* ptr)
{
    free(ptr);
}
```